# Unable to print from fstream

Tags: c++, file, c++11, io, fstream

I am trying to change a file's open mode from `ios::in | ios::out` to only `ios::out` by closing the open file and opening in the new mode. I have stored my `fstream` inside a class `file_handler` whose member functions read and write from/to the file. But after opening in the new mode, the functions do not seem to work.Here's my code (adapted from a bigger program for the question here) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class file_handler
{
protected:
    fstream file;
    string path;
public:
    void file_open();
    void print();
};

void file_handler::file_open()
{
    cout << "\n ENter filename : ";
    cin >> path;
    file.open(path, ios::out | ios::in);
}

class html : public file_handler
{
    string  title, body;
public:
    void get_data();
    void write_file();
};

void html::get_data()
{
    cout << "\n enter title : ";
    cin >> title;
    cout << "\n enter body : ";
    fflush(stdin);
    cin >> body;
}

void html::write_file()
{
    file.close();
    file.open(path, ios::out);
    file.seekg(0);
    file << "\n title : " << title << "\n body : " << body;
    print();
}

void file_handler::print()
{
    cout << "\n\n Here is your html file";
    string temp;
    while(getline(file, temp))
        cout << temp << endl;
}

int main()
{
    html F;
    F.file_open();
    F.get_data();
    F.write_file();
}
```

Can you point out the mistake(s) and kindly suggest a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**The errors encountered :** 
1. The file I want to have created is not found anywhere on the pc(`write_file()` possibly doesn't work)
2. `print()` does not "print the file"(although it executes the `cout` statement with no problem)

Comment: please be specific on the error you are facing

Comment: I updated the post being more specific. Just run the program, you'll see what i'm talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close your file in write_file():

```
void html::write_file()
{
    file.close();
    file.open(path, ios::out);
    file.seekg(0);
    file << "\n title : " << title << "\n body : " << body;
    file.close();
    print();
}
```

Then in `print()`, you should re-open it:

```
void file_handler::print()
{
    cout << "\n\n Here is your html file";
    file.open(path);
    string temp;
    while (getline(file, temp))
        cout << temp << endl;
    file.close();
}
```

I would suggest checking `file.isOpen()` to make sure you are actually opening the file. Check the running directory for the output file.

Additionally, I would recommend using RAII with files. Add a destructor to your `file_handler` class which closes the file if it is open. Add some more error checking. You can even remove your call to `print()` from `write_file()` and call `print()` separately.

Comment: Can you tell why the error occurs in the first place?

Comment: The problem occurs because you are not separating the write from the read. You should open the file, write the data, close it. Then, to print, you should open, read the data, close it. In your original implementation, the file is ultimately left open (from write_file) and then it is never closed.